# Efficiently calculating mathematical formulas with exponents

Tags: python

I'm implementing a program that calculates an equation: F(n) = F(n-1) + 'a' + func1(func2(F(n-1))).

func1 takes every 'a' and makes it 'c' and every 'c' becomes 'a'.

func2 reverses the string (e.x. "xyz" becomes "zyx").

I want to calculate the Kth character of F(10**2017).
The basic rules are F(0) = "" (empty string), and examples are F(1) = "a", F(2) = "aac", and so on.

How do I do this efficiently?

The basic part of my code is this:

```
def op1 (str1):
     if str1 == 'a':
          return 'c'
     else:
          return 'a'

def op2 (str2):
     return str2[::-1]

sinitial = ''

while (counter < 10**2017):
    Finitial = Finitial + 'a' + op1(op2(Finitial))
    counter += 1

print Finitial
```

Comment: Did you try a recursive method?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks! Could you please be more specific? How could I implement it?

Comment: How is `F(1)="a"` when there is no `"a"` character mentioned in the definition of `F()` but there is an `"m"` character? `F(2)="aac"` also makes no sense.

Comment: What is `K` (as in "Kth character")? Are you aware that `F(10**2017)` has `2**(10**2017)-1` characters, and that that's an insanely huge number?

Comment: Hint: compute `s=F(5)`, and write down a table with `s[i-1]` against the binary expansion of `i`, for `i >= 1`. See if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: I'll try that, Mark. Thanks

Comment: If the above hint isn't enough, see also https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128877.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's start by fixing your original code and defining a function to compute `F(n)` for small `n`. We'll also print out the first few values of `F`. All code below is for Python 3; if you're using Python 2, you'll need to make some minor changes, like replacing `str.maketrans` with `string.maketrans` and `range` with `xrange`.

```
swap_ac = str.maketrans({ord('a'): 'c', ord('c'): 'a'})

def F(n):
    s = ''
    for _ in range(n):
        s = s + 'a' + s[::-1].translate(swap_ac)
    return s

for n in range(7):
    print("F({}) = {!r}".format(n, F(n)))
```

This gives the following output:

```
F(0) = ''
F(1) = 'a'
F(2) = 'aac'
F(3) = 'aacaacc'
F(4) = 'aacaaccaaaccacc'
F(5) = 'aacaaccaaaccaccaaacaacccaaccacc'
F(6) = 'aacaaccaaaccaccaaacaacccaaccaccaaacaaccaaaccacccaacaacccaaccacc'
```

A couple of observations at this point:

1. `F(n)` is a string of length `2**n-1`. That means that `F(n)` grows *fast*. Computing `F(50)` would already require some serious hardware: even if we stored one character per bit, we'd need over 100 terabytes to store the full string. `F(200)` has more characters than there are estimated atoms in the solar system. So the idea of *computing* `F(10**2017)` directly is laughable: we need a different approach.
2. By construction, each `F(n)` is a prefix of `F(n+1)`. So what we really have is a well-defined *infinite* string, where each `F(n)` merely gives us the first `2**n-1` characters of that infinite string, and we're looking to compute its `k`th character. And for any practical purpose, `F(10**2017)` might as well *be* that infinite string: for example, when we do our computation, we don't need to check that `k < 2**(10**2017)-1`, since a `k` exceeding this can't even be represented in normal binary notation in this universe.

Luckily, the structure of the string is simple enough that computing the `k`th character directly is straightforward. The major clue comes when we look at the characters at even and odd positions:

```
>>> F(6)[::2]
'acacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac'
>>> F(6)[1::2]
'aacaaccaaaccaccaaacaacccaaccacc'
```

The characters at *even* positions simply alternate between `a` and `c` (and it's straightforward to prove that this is true, based on the construction). So if our `k` is even, we can simply look at whether `k/2` is odd or even to determine whether we'll get an `a` or a `c`.

What about the odd positions? Well `F(6)[1::2]` should look somewhat familiar: it's just `F(5)`:

```
>>> F(6)[1::2] == F(5)
True
```

Again, it's straightforward to prove (e.g., by induction) that this isn't simply a coincidence, and that `F(n+1)[1::2] == F(n)` for all nonnegative `n`.

We now have an effective way to compute the `k`th character in our infinite string: if `k` is even, we just look at the parity of `k/2`. If `k` is odd, then we know that the character at position `k` is equal to that at position `(k-1)/2`. So here's a first solution to computing that character:

```
def char_at_pos(k):
    """
    Return the character at position k of the string F(n), for any
    n satisfying 2**n-1 > k.
    """
    while k % 2 == 1:
        k //= 2
    return 'ac'[k//2%2]
```

And a check that this does the right thing:

```
>>> ''.join(char_at_pos(i) for i in range(2**6-1))
'aacaaccaaaccaccaaacaacccaaccaccaaacaaccaaaccacccaacaacccaaccacc'
>>> ''.join(char_at_pos(i) for i in range(2**6-1)) == F(6)
True
```

But we can do better. We're effectively staring at the binary representation of `k`, removing all trailing `'1'`s and the next `'0'`, then simply looking at the next bit to determine whether we've got an `'a'` or a `'c'`. Identifying the trailing 1s can be done by bit-operation trickery. This gives us the following semi-obfuscated loop-free solution, which I leave it to you to unwind:

```
def char_at_pos2(k):
    """
    Return the character at position k of the string F(n), for any
    n satisfying 2**n-1 > k.
    """
    return 'ac'[k//(1+(k+1^k))%2]
```

Again, let's check:

```
>>> F(20) == ''.join(char_at_pos2(i) for i in range(2**20-1))
True
```

Final comments: this is a very well-known and well-studied sequence: it's called the dragon curve sequence, or the [regular paper-folding sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_paperfolding_sequence), and is [sequence A014577](https://oeis.org/A014577) in the online encyclopaedia of integer sequences. Some Google searches will likely give you many other ways to compute its elements. See also [this codegolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128858).

Comment: Another dazzling display of mathematical prowess!  Thank you, I learned something new.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I understood the logic behind your explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Based on what you have already coded, here's my suggestion:

```
def main_function(num):
    if num == 0:
        return ''
    previous = main_function(num-1)
    return previous + 'a' + op1(op2(previous))

print(main_function(10**2017))
```

P.S: I'm not sure of the efficiency.

Comment: I suggest you try running this for e.g. `num=40` and see what happens.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I know it'll blow up and I would have to wait for long. But the OP wanted a recursive approach, so I just did that.

Comment: Yes, for such large numbers like 10**2017 it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work for large numbers? Thanks!

Comment: @Eddev: You have no hope of actually computing `F(100)`, let alone `F(10**2017)`; it's just way too large. Nevertheless, it's possible to find a way to compute the `i`th entry in `F(10**2017)` without actually needing to compute `F(10**2017)` first.

Comment: @SamChats even for num = 40, the program doesn't work since it returns all as 'a'.

Comment: @MarkDickinson right, which is why I only wish to compute the ith entry. Could you kindly answer this question and guide me on this?

Comment: @Eddev It shouldn't return all 'a's if `op1` is correctly defined.